# Why are these two positions ignored?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinate-systems

I am writing some javascript to create x and y coodinates from an array, so i have this code:

```
var map1 = [
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
    gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,gg,
];
  for (var i=0; i<map1.length; i++) {
    if (i > 16) {
        dy = Math.floor(i / 15) * 16;
    }
    dx = i * 16
    while (dx >= 240) {
        dx = dx - 240;
    }   
  }
```

And the code works extremely well, except for coordinates 0,1 and 1,1 arent working? These coordinates are building a canvas with 16px blocks using the principal on this page [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Using_images?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Canvas_tutorial/Using_images). And `dx` and `dy` fit into this equation, `ctx.drawImage(tileset, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);` Thanks!

Comment: I assume dx and dy are the coordinates?   What are the current values of 0,1 and 1,1 and what did you expect them to be?

Comment: `dy` is only defined under a condition. Where is it saying whats its value the first time the loop runs? Its a big mess code missing commas and with a crazy nonsense `while`.

Comment: yet it is under a condition in a for loop, the while is to bring gown past 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps - but the following snippet in the console seems to give the correct results for all positions. Can you perhaps explain what output you're expecting vs the actual output you're getting ?

```
var map1 = new Array(225);
var dx, dy;

for (var i=0; i<map1.length; i++) {
    if (i > 16) {
       dy = Math.floor(i / 15) * 16;
    }
    dx = i * 16
    while (dx >= 240) {
        dx = dx - 240;
    }
    console.log(dx + ',' + dy); //Seems to print all positions ok
}
```

Comment: That code still doesn't explicitly define `dy` ahead of time, but at least by using `var` you shadow any possible existing value with undefined.
Why not something like this inside the for body:

    `dx = (i & 15) << 4; dy = (i >> 4) << 4;`
Faster math here too.

Comment: wait, this is wrong, those two still arent fixed and now the entire first line is undefined in its dy value

Comment: no, you were right it does work, but i have to set `var dx = 0;` and `var dx = 0;`

Comment: yet the iutput is the same i have to do those two blocks of 0,1 and 1,1 manualy